# Different rewrite mode for CFWheels website root

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion, url-rewriting, apache2, cfwheels

I need an advice on researching the following issue.

Wheels website has `set(URLRewriting="On")` configured, everything looks fine except root page.

All links built with `linkTo` look like `website.tld/controller/action`.

But on a / mode "switched" into the partial and links look like  `website.tld/index.cfm/controller/action`. Interestingly, if default route page accessed explicitly (/pages/index in this case) -- URLs built properly.

Website is running in Tomcat with Apache2 under Ubuntu, standard Wheels rewriting rules configured directly in a vhost config, as a workaround to known issue with .htaccess.

Where to start? What variables to check and how to debug this?

Thanks.

**UPD** All I can see for now is that when default action accessed directly there's no `Route: home` in the debug output. Not sure how to use this info, I have very small experience with Wheels.

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer, so I'll leave as a comment. Usually Wheels will ignore `set(urlRewriting="On")` if you're not rewriting to `rewrite.cfm`. Make sure that requests are routing through `rewrite.cfm` and not `index.cfm`.

Comment: @Chris I've checked the CGI scope and the script was `index.cfm`. I've fixed the rewriting rules and now everything is fine, please post your comment as answer, I will mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [Chris Peters](/users/175981/chris-peters) did not create the answer, I'll do this instead just to mark the question resolved. All glory to Chris, any way.

*Usually Wheels will ignore set(urlRewriting="On") if you're not rewriting to rewrite.cfm. Make sure that requests are routing through rewrite.cfm and not index.cfm*

It means that you need to check the *CGI* scope on the problematic pages and fix the rewriting workaround rules (there are few of them for Tomcat+CFWheels, I think).

Comment: Just now noticed that you asked me to put it as an answer. Gotta check my email notification settings. :-/ Glad you got it sorted out though!

Answer (score 2):

I have a very similar setup and ran into the same problem just now. As a temporary workaround I found that by changing line 294 of wheels/global/public.cfm from

```
loc.returnValue = application.wheels.webPath & ListLast(request.cgi.script_name, "/");
```

to

```
loc.returnValue = application.wheels.webPath;
```

that linkTo() built a path that worked with URL rewriting. I'll ping some friends more familiar with Wheels to see if there's a patch required to fix this.

Comment: I just realised this might not be exactly the same situation - my problem was that linkTo() was writing /index.cfm/controller/action when rewriting was enabled instead of /controller/action.

Comment: Robin, your problem looks exactly the same -- incorrect inserting of `/index.cfm/` into the generated URL. Thanks for the workaround, though also I'd like to hear some thoughts from Wheels developers, I know some of them are SO users too.